# How to use Selenium using Xpath to determine the classes of an element?

Tags: xpath, selenium, getattribute

I am trying to use xpath within selenium to select a div element that is within a td.
What I am really trying to do is determine the class of the div and if it is either classed `LOGO1, LOGO2, LOGO3` and so on. Originally I was going to just snag the `image:url` to determine with logo.jpg was used but whoever made the target website used one image for each logo type and used css to determine which portion of the image will be displayed. So Imagine 4 images on one sprite image. This is the reason why I have to determine the class of the div instead of digging through the css paths.

In selenium I am using storeElementPresent | `/html/body/form/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[3]/div[2]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[${i}]/td[8]/div//class | cardLogo .`

The div has multiple classes so I am thinking that this is the issue, but any help is appreciated. Below is the target source. This is source from within the table in the tbody. Selenium has no problems identifying all the way up to td[8] but then fails to gather the div. Please help!

```
<td class="togglehidefields" style="width:80px;">
<div class="cardlogo LOGO1" style="background-image:url(https://www.somesite.com/merchants/images/image.jpg)"></div>
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdCCChargebackDetail_lblCardNumber_0">7777</span>
</td>
```

I was fiddling with `selenium.getAttribute()` but it kept erroring out, any ideas there?

Comment: I don't think i quite understood what you're trying to do, you just want to retrieve the div based on the specific class?

Comment: This is difficult to understand. You are getting your `DIV` element. Great, then what do you want to do with it? Why does `.getAttribute` error? With what error? How are you calling it?

Answer (score 4):

This `<div/>` element has one class attribute with one value, but this one is tokenized when parsed as HTML.

As selenium only supports **XPath 1.0**, you will need to check for classes like this:

```
//div[contains(@class, "LOGO1") or contains(@class, "LOGO2")]
```

Extend that pattern as needed and embed it in your expression.

With **XPath 2.0** and better, you could tokenize and use the `=` operator which works on a set-based semantics:

```
//div[tokenize(@class, ' ') = ("LOGO1", "LOGO2")]
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. To answer the questions above, I had originally just wanted to catch the div and then getAttributes()  for its class names.Instead I just catch the div class and check to see if its class is LOGO1 or LOGO2 etc... this seemed to work best for my situation.

<code>
storeElementPresent | //table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_grdCCChargebackDetail']/x:tbody/x:tr[${i}]/x:td[8]/x:div[@class='cardlogo LOGO1'] | visa

storeElementPresent | //table[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_grdCCChargebackDetail']/x:tbody/x:tr[${i}]/x:td[8]/x:div[@class='cardlogo LOGO2'] | mastercard
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I'll put the solution I used up just in case it can help anyone.

```
xpath=//div[contains(@class,'carouselNavNext ')]/.[contains(@class, 'disabled')]
```

Fire of your contains, and then follow with `/.` to check children AND the current element.